# ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected. Soldity ^0.8;

Tags: interface, ethereum, solidity, parse-error, remix

I am facing an issue in solidity where When I declare the interface, it throws the error as shown in the title. at line 9

> from solidity: ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected. --> contracts/Program4.sol:9:3: | 9 | interface IL1ERC20Bridg

I checked the syntax and a few other errors of the same type on stack overflow, but to no avail.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90841/parsererror-function-variable-struct-or-modifier-declaration-expected
I tried this one, but there is no incorrect white spaces.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120469/why-am-i-getting-function-variable-struct-or-modifier-declaration-expected
The author had put a semicolan at the end thus prompting the error.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import {SafeERC20} from '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol';
import {Address} from '@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol';
contract LendingPool 
{
  interface IL1ERC20Bridge{
    event ERC20DepositInitiated(
        address indexed _l1Token, address indexed _l2Token,
        address indexed _from, address _to, uint256 _amount, bytes _data);


    event ERC20WithdrawalFinalized(
        address indexed _l1Token, address indexed _l2Token,
        address indexed _from, address _to, uint256 _amount, bytes _data);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare an interface inside a contract. This type must be declared outside the smart contract and only in this way you can define an instance and call its methods or events . For this last operation you can use this statement:

```
[nameInterface] [nameVariable];
```

I adjusted your smart contract in this way:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import {SafeERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import {Address} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";

interface IL1ERC20Bridge {
    event ERC20DepositInitiated(
        address indexed _l1Token, address indexed _l2Token,
        address indexed _from, address _to, uint256 _amount, bytes _data);


    event ERC20WithdrawalFinalized(
        address indexed _l1Token, address indexed _l2Token,
        address indexed _from, address _to, uint256 _amount, bytes _data);
  }

contract LendingPool {
    IL1ERC20Bridge myInterface;

    // Your logic below this line...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with the same issue. Just trying to close the contract with this. I added a semicolon, and still have the parse error, from solidity:

```
ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.
  --> stable coin lil.sol:54:1:
   |
54 | 
   | ^
```

How do I fix it?

```
function marketing(uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
  uint256 marketingTaxAmount = amount.mul(MARKETING_TAX).div(100);

  _transfer(address(this), _msgSender(), marketingTaxAmount);
}
```

Comment: Not sure about this, I recommend you create a new question for more visibility

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34670068)